# How do I let the user multiply two numbers as well as let them multiply a string?

Tags: c

What I mean by this is, I'm writing a program where the user inputs a string along with a `'*'` character and any number, and the program multiplies the string the user entered by that number

```
Please enter a string you'd like multiplied: horse*3

output:
horsehorsehorse
```

What I'd like to do is, if that string happens to be a number, then multiply the two numbers like you normally would

```
Please enter a string you'd like multiplied: 2*2

output:
4
```

I'm putting my code down below.

```
int multStr(char *strMult) //strMult is character array for initial input
{
    //printf("\nRedirected to here!\n");

    printf("Please enter a string and number you'd like to multiply by: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", strMult); //User scans in the string intended for multiplication

    char string[255];           //Character array for the string part
    char number[255];           //Character array for the number the string is to be multiplied by

    int counter=0;
    int i;

    for(i=0;strMult[i] != '*'; i++)
    {
        string[i] = strMult[i];
        counter++;
    }

    if(string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9')
    {
        int strNum = myAtoi(string);
        printf("String: %d", strNum);
    }

    else
        {
        printf("String: %s\n", string);
        }

    counter++;

    for(i=0; strMult[counter] != '\0'; counter++, i++)
    {
        number[i] = strMult[counter];
    }
    //number[i+1] = '\0';
    printf("Number: %s\n", number);


    int num = myAtoi(number);

    //printf("Number after convert: %d\n", num);
    for(i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", string);
    }

    printf("\n");


    return(0);


}
```

strMult is a char array I called from main. I was not able to use stdlib, so I created my own Atoi function

Comment: Whats wrong with your current code?

Comment: Right now I am able to multiply a string by a number. I need to add something that turns that string into an integer, probably with the myAtoi function, and does a standard multiplication

Comment: Are you asking how to check if the string can be turned into a number?

Comment: Use `strtol` to convert the string.   If it doesn't consume the whole string (eg, the end pointer passed in the second argument come back not pointing to the terminating null), then treat the entry as a string.  Otherwise, treat it as a number.

Comment: You can try to check if the string is some_chars + * + a number, and in this case you multiply the string. If the string is some_numbers + * + some_numbers you multiply numbers. You can try with regular expressions : https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-write-regular-expressions-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues here. The first thing you're doing is splitting the string into two `char[]`s `string` and `number`. You seem to do that ok. The next thing you need to do is to check that `string` is a number.

```
if(string[i] >= '0' && string[i] <= '9')
{
    int strNum = myAtoi(string);
    printf("String: %d", strNum);
}

else
{
    printf("String: %s\n", string);
}
```

This is what you're using, but note that it has no consequence to the rest of the program. Your number is local to the if block, and then it goes away, so you cannot use it later. What you want to do, is make the number available later.

```
int isNumber = 1;
int strNum;   

for(int k = 0; k < i; k++){
    if( string[k] >= '0' && string[k]<='9' ){
        //continue checking
    }else{
        isNumber=0;
    }
}

if (isNumber==1){
    strNum = myAtoi(string);
} else{
    // print your string or some such.
}
```

Note that I check all of the characters in the string, and not just the '*' which is the character at the i'th position. That way, if somebody enters horse42*2, it will think it is a string.

Also, you can improve this by checking the values as you separate out the number.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a useful tool for parsing user input.  Reading unconstrained user input with scanf is dangerous because unexpectedly long input will overflow the buffer.

Here is an example that use getline for reading input safely and regular expressions to sort out the format for the user input.

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TERM "(([[:digit:]]+)|([[:alpha:]]+))"

void string_by_number(int number, char *string)
{
  printf("number %d  string %s\n", number, string);
  for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
    printf("%s", string);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  regex_t re;
  regmatch_t capture[7];

  if (regcomp(&re, TERM "[[:space:]]*[*][[:space:]]*" TERM, REG_EXTENDED)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error in regular expression pattern\n");
    return 1;
  }

  char   *line = NULL;
  size_t  line_size = 0;

  printf("Please enter a string you'd like multiplied: ");
  while (0 < getline(&line, &line_size, stdin)) {
    if (regexec(&re, line, 7, capture, 0)) {
      printf("Unexpected input '%s'\n", line);
      continue;
    }

    int   format = 0;
    char *lhs_string = NULL;
    int   lhs_number;
    char *rhs_string = NULL;
    int   rhs_number;

    if (capture[2].rm_so >= 0) {
      format ^= 0x01;
      lhs_number = strtol(&line[capture[2].rm_so], NULL, 10);
    } 
    else {
      lhs_string = &line[capture[3].rm_so];
      line[capture[3].rm_eo] = '\0';
    }

    if (capture[5].rm_so >= 0) {
      format ^= 0x02;
      rhs_number = strtol(&line[capture[5].rm_so], NULL, 10);
    } 
    else {
      rhs_string = &line[capture[6].rm_so];
      line[capture[6].rm_eo] = '\0';
    }

    switch (format) {
      case 0x00: printf("Can't do 'string' * 'string'\n"); break;
      case 0x01: string_by_number(lhs_number, rhs_string); break;
      case 0x02: string_by_number(rhs_number, lhs_string); break;
      case 0x03: printf("%d\n", lhs_number * rhs_number); break;
    }

    printf("\nPlease enter a string you'd like multiplied: ");
  }

  free(line);
  regfree(&re);

  return 0;
}
```